# Relation of Sampling frequency, Signal length (datapoints) and Time range of Discrete Wavelet Transform?

Tags: matlab, fft, wavelet, frequency-analysis, dwt

As above lets Fs is sampling frequency, L is signal's length and t is time range.

As using *mdwtdec* in Matlab in order to decompose multi-raw signal into specific frequency band, I just notice that decomposed signal's length at 1st level is split into half, and keep slit into half of 1st level signal at 2nd level.

Raw signal's time range calculation: t = 0 --> (L/Fs)

My question is in every decomposition level the Sampling frequency Fs is still the same? and at every decomposition level how I can calculate the time range of each Detail and Approximation coefficient.

Also as verify the frequency band of Discrete Wavelet Transform I applied FFT at each level following this post: https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html?lang=en

According to this post my first question need to be answered.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty positive that in discrete wavelet transform, the time series data or signals, if we wish, would be downsampled by a factor of 2, which means that if we would be having 2^10 or 1024 datapoints in our original time series data, in the first level, it would be divided into 2 and our level one sampling frequency would be 2^9 or 512, in second level would decrease to 256, and so on.

However, in continuous wavelet transform, it would most likely remain the same.

[image]

Based on the references, I copy some codes here that you might want to test and see, you might want to reduce the number of levels and Fs here and you can define your own `x` if you wish:

```
 Fs = 1e6;
 t = 0:1/Fs:1-1/Fs;
 x = cos(2*pi*50*t);
 [C,L] = wavedec(x,15,'db4');
 details = detcoef(C,L,'cells');
 d14recon = wrcoef('d',C,L,'db4',14);
 plot(d14recon,'k'); 
 d13recon = wrcoef('d',C,L,'db4',13);
 hold on;
 plot(d13recon,'r');  %look how small the amplitude is

 a13recon = wrcoef('a',C,L,'db4',13);
 plot(a13recon,'b');
```

#### Useful Links:

I'm not expert about it, you can likely read more about it and find out your desired information. There are also lots of YouTube videos about it.

[Discrete wavelet transform relation to sampling frequency of the signal](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38611-discrete-wavelet-transform-relation-to-sampling-frequency-of-the-signal)

[Single-level discrete 2-D wavelet transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html)